# Ng-Repeat array to rows and columns

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Thanks for taking the time to read this, I was wondering how I might be able to use ng-repeat to create a grid like box of options.  I would like to take an array repeat nth number of items and then move to the next row or column until all items are listed. e.g.

assuming I had an array like `[opt1,opt2,opt3,opt4,opt5,opt6,opt7]` I would like to display it like this:

```
opt1 opt2 opt3
opt4 opt5 opt6
opt7
```

Comment: Here is another solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21653981/131157

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27211799/angular-ng-repeat-add-bootstrap-row-every-3-or-4-cols

Answer (score 18):

This is more a styling/markup problem than an AngularJS one. If you really want to, you can do:

```
<span ng:repeat="(index, value) in array">
    {{value}}<br ng:show="(index+1)%3==0" />
</span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JG3A5/

Comment: How do we use this method to create a table with three columns?

Comment: @kumareloaded Why not just use a <table> with three columns.

Answer (score 10):

Sorry for my HAML and Bootstrap3:

```
.row
  .col-lg-4
    %div{'ng:repeat' => "item in array.slice(0, array.length / 3)"}
      {{item}}
  .col-lg-4
    %div{'ng:repeat' => "item in array.slice(array.length / 3, array.length * 2/3)"}
      {{item}}
  .col-lg-4
    %div{'ng:repeat' => "item in array.slice(array.length * 2/3, array.length)"}
      {{item}}
```

There is another version, with possibility to use filters:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="remainder in [0,1,2]">
    <span ng-repeat="item in array" ng-if="$index % 3 == remainder">{{item}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

If all of your items are in one single array, your best bet is to make a grid in CSS. This article should be helpful: http://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-it-grids/

You can use $index from ng-repeat to apply the correct class for your column (in this case a 4 column grid):

```
<div class="col-{{ $index % 4 }}"></div>
```

If you have a 2 dimensional array (split into rows and columns) that opens up more possibilities like actually using an HTML table.

Answer (score 2):

I find it easier to simply use ng-repeat combined with ng-if and offsetting any indexes using $index. Mind the jade below:

```
div(ng-repeat="product in products")
    div.row(ng-if="$index % 2 === 0")
      div.col(ng-init="p1 = products[$index]")
          span p1.Title
      div.col(ng-if="products.length > $index + 1", ng-init="p2 = products[$index + 1]")
          span p2.Title
      div.col(ng-if="products.length <= $index + 1")
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Between Performance, Dynamics and Readability

**It seems putting the logic in your JavaScript is the best method. I would just bite-the-bullet and look into:**

```
function listToMatrix(list, n) {
    var grid = [], i = 0, x = list.length, col, row = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        col = i % n;
        if (col === 0) {
            grid[++row] = [];
        }
        grid[row][col] = list[i];
    }
    return grid;
}

var matrix = listToMatrix(lists, 3);
console.log('#RedPill', matrix);
```

- @ Params: (list, n)

  - Where list is any array and n is an arbitrary number of columns desired per row
- @ Return: A matroid
- @ Note: This function is designed to orient a matroid based upon an arbitrary number of columns with variance in its number of rows. In other words, x = desired-columns, y = n.

You can then create an angular `filter` to handle this:

Filter:

```
angular.module('lists', []).filter('matrical', function() {
    return function(list, columns) {
        return listToMatrix(list, columns);
    };
});
```

Controller:

```
function listOfListsController($scope) {
    $scope.lists = $http.get('/lists');
}
```

View:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="row in (lists | matrical:3)">
    <div class="col col-33" ng-repeat="list in row">{{list.name}}</div>
</div>
```

With this, you can see you get `n` number of rows -- each containing "`3`" columns. When you change the number of desired columns, you'll notice the number of rows changes accordingly (*assuming the list-length is always the same ;)*).

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cCarlson/hy843ukk/7/).

*Note, that you get the ol' `Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`. This is because Angular is recalling the `matrical` function upon every iteration. Allegedly, you can use the `as results` alias to prevent Angular from reevaluating the collection, but I had no luck. For this, it may be better to filter the grid inside of your controller and use that value for your repeater: `$filter('matrical')(items)` -- **but please post back if you come across an elegant way of filtering it in the `ng-repeat`**.*

I would stress, again, you're probably heading down a dark alley by trying to write the logic in your view -- but I encourage you to try it in your view if you haven't already.

#### Edit

*The use of this algorithm should be combined with a **Matrical Data-Structure** to provide methods of `push`, `pop`, `splice`, and additional methods -- in tandem with appropriate logic to complement **Bi-Directional Data-Binding** if desired. In other words, data-binding will not work out of the box (of course) as when a new item is added to your list, a reevaluation of the entire list must take place to keep the matrix's structural integrity.*

***Suggestion:** Use the `$filter('matrical')($scope.list)` syntax in combination with `$scope.$watch` and recompile/calculate item-positions for the matrix.*

Cheers!