# AngularJS Loops and Formatting with ng-repeat for image and link text

Tags: css, angularjs, image, anchor, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to be able to arrange a list of images (4 in my case) to a row and the link text to appear below like so:

```
row1
image1          image2           image3         image4
linkText1       linkText2        linkText3      linkText4

row2 
image5          image6....
linkText5       linkText6.....
```

and so for however many images are. Here whether you click on the image or on its linkText, its supposed to open a document in a new window.

Here's the html that I intend, but doesn't work the way I want. It just puts one image per row. I have tried various combinations nothing seems to work. Although if I use just the img element and use the ng-repeat on it, the images flow the way I want, 4 to a row, but that doesn't serve my purpose as I want the link text as well below each image.

```
    <div ng-repeat="items in DocImageCollection ">
        <div ng-repeat="row in items">
          <img alt="{{row.linkText}}" 
ng-click="$event.preventDefault();openDocument({{row}});" ng-src="{{row.imageSrc}}" imageonload />
          <br />
          <span ng-click="$event.preventDefault();openDocument({{row}});"> 
           {{row.linkText}}</span>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Here 
   imageonload is a directive which I have created for downloading the 
       image source,
   DocImageCollection - is the main collection; for e.g. if I have 10 images in
     all, then this will be an object array of capacity = 3, where each array 
    element (row) is itself an array of 4 image objects
  I have all the data correct, I just have issue in the templating. Any help is
  greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `div` tag is a block level element so it'll appear on it's own line unless you change the CSS display attribute to `inline-block`.  Specifically, you need to target the display attribute for the `div` that contains the `img` and link.

Here's an example on codepen:
http://codepen.io/gwmccull/pen/LpYLLp

Comment: I did try that as well using the display attribute, didn't help.

Comment: gwmccull - can you please provide me with a sample markup?

Comment: gwmccull - Thanks a bunch, can't say enough. I was able to tweak it to suit my needs.

Comment: @user428602 Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use an indexing method with your `ng-repeat`.

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cpatoquq/)

Adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27211799/angular-ng-repeat-add-bootstrap-row-every-3-or-4-cols)

ps. Not necessarily you will use the `ng-if`, this only serves you in case you want to only show multiples of 4

Comment: Will this work with image and a link text below each image, with the indexing method that you have suggested? Sample would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It will work. You just have to place them both inside the same element and arrange the layout to be one on top the of the other. Also, watch for the sum of your images sizes and your screen canvas, it might cut some images out. I am sorry but I am kinda in the middle of something and won't be able to create you an example right now, but it should be pretty quick.