# Sorting in ng-repeat with row after every 4th column

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, angularjs-ng-repeat

To create a grid of items with 4 products max per row, [we can do the following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27211799/angular-ng-repeat-add-bootstrap-row-every-3-or-4-cols/30259461#30259461):

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products" ng-if="$index % 4 == 0" class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">{{products[$index]}}</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">{{products[$index + 1]}}</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">{{products[$index + 2]}}</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">{{products[$index + 3]}}</div>
</div>
```

However, if I try to add:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products | orderBy: '-value.timestamp_creation'" ng-if="$index % 4 == 0" class="row">
      <!-- see above -->
</div>
```

where `products` looks as follows (array):

```
[
  {name: "John", value: {timestamp_creation: 1}}, 
  {name: "Andrew", value: {timestamp_creation: 4}},
  {name: "Senior", value: {timestamp_creation: 2}}
  {name: "Dog", value: {timestamp_creation: 3}}
]
```

Then it does not work to sort the grid. It just shows the order 1,4,2,3.

Note that the following way to sort the grid works (but then I don't get a row after every 4th column)

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products | orderBy: '-value.timestamp_creation'" class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">{{product}}</div>
</div>
```

**So how to combine these two approaches, to get a column after every 4th item but still be able to sort the list?**

Answer (score 1):

It should work. Which angular version you're using. I checked in fiddle with every 2nd row.

See [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/20205/)

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="product in products | orderBy: '-value.timestamp_creation'" ng-if="$index % 2 === 0" class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">{{product}}</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.products = [
        {name: "John", value: {timestamp_creation: 1}}, 
        {name: "Andrew", value: {timestamp_creation: 4}},
        {name: "Senior", value: {timestamp_creation: 2}},
        {name: "Dog", value: {timestamp_creation: 3}},
        {name: "John 1", value: {timestamp_creation: 7}}, 
        {name: "Andrew 1", value: {timestamp_creation: 6}},
        {name: "Senior 1", value: {timestamp_creation: 8}},
        {name: "Dog 1", value: {timestamp_creation: 5}}
    ];
}
```

Comment: Using 1.4.5... still not working for my data. How can I check whats wrong?

Comment: Print your json data and paste it over here. Make sure there is no error in console.