# AngularJS ng-repeat for rows and items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have Ionic app. Now I have below code.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-33" ng-repeat="(key, value) in categoryMenuOut">
    <a href="#/category/{{chosenCat}}/{{key}}">
       `some code`
       <span class="name">{{value.name}}</span>
     </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

But it's broken on Android 4.0.0 and I need repeat rows and 3 items in the row. I need something like this.

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="(key, value) in categoryMenuOut">
   <div class="col col-33">
    <a href="#/category/{{chosenCat}}/{{key}}">
      `some code`
       <span class="name">{{value.name}}</span>
     </a>
   </div>
   <div class="col col-33">
    <a href="#/category/{{chosenCat}}/{{key}}">
      `some code`
       <span class="name">{{value.name}}</span>
     </a>
   </div>
   <div class="col col-33">
    <a href="#/category/{{chosenCat}}/{{key}}">
      `some code`
       <span class="name">{{value.name}}</span>
     </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

I need key and value in the ng-repeat. I didn't find solution for me.
Can you help me please.

Update: If I use one row the items on the Android 4.0.0 doesn't transfer to a new line. I need repeat rows and in the rows I need see 3 different items.
I have tried [Angular ng-repeat add bootstrap row every 3 or 4 cols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27211799/angular-ng-repeat-add-bootstrap-row-every-3-or-4-cols) this solution, but I have (key, value) and it doesn't suit me.
[image]

Comment: What is broken? This seems valid.

Comment: *"it's broken"* is not a proper problem statement. Also no idea what you mean in last sentence since you already show key and value. Please review [ask]

Comment: If I use one row  the items on the Android 4.0.0 doesn't transfer to a new line. I need repeat rows and in the rows I need see 3 different items.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use [collection-repeat](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/collectionRepeat/) with ion-list?

Comment: Hello. That's not what I need. I need repeat rows and in the one row see 3  different items.

Answer (score 0):

This seems valid, but maybe you want to do like something like this:

```js
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('myCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
  $scope.categoryMenuOut =  {"Ben": {"name": "bill"}, "Nate": {"name": "joll"}, "Austin": {"name": "boll"}};

}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div ng-app='myApp'>
  <div ng-controller='myCtrl'>
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="(key, value) in categoryMenuOut  track by $index">
     
  <div class="col col-33">
        <h3>Key: {{key}}</h3> 
       <h4>Value: {{value.name}}
     </div>

         <div class="col col-33">
        <h3>Key: {{key}}</h3> 
       <h4>Value: {{value.name}}
     </div>
    
    <div class="col col-33">
        <h3>Key: {{key}}</h3> 
       <h4>Value: {{value.name}}
     </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough, but I will try to answer it.

First of all you should not use `href` with an angular template string, because there is a chance the link would point to a non-existing page (before the digest loop completes). Use `ng-href` instead.

Source: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

If I understood your problem right, you cannot access all of your values in the object from `ng-repeat`, this is because you have probably not structured your JS object properly.

For example `(name, age) in {'adam':10, 'amalie':12}`, would result in name first being adam and then amaile, the same goes for age.

In order for your `(key, value)` to work properly, your `categoryMenuOut` should have a structure similar to:

```
$scope.categoryMenuOut = {
    pizza1: {
       name: 'Pepperoni'
    }
}
```

or even better:

```
$scope.categoryMenuOut = [
    {
       name: 'Pepperoni'
    },
    {
       name: 'Salad'
    }
]
```

In my first example your key would be `pizza1`, the `value` will be the whole object `{ name: 'Pepperoni' }`, therefore the `value.name` will be equal to `Pepperoni`. In this case you have full control over the key's name. If you do it as in the second example, your keys would be `0, 1..`.

Try to reword your question next time, in order for us to understand it and for you to receive a proper answer.