# How make diffrent section of ng-repeat data in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some data and display using ng-repeat which print following

```
data1
data2
data3
data4
data5
data6
```

but I want to print these data divided by sections. such as

```
data1    data3    data5
data2    data4    data6
```

Is it possible in angularjs ?

Comment: use ng-if or ng-switch in ng-repeat using that you can achive that
using conditional statement add classes

Comment: Please create fiddle of your code

Comment: are you using any css framework like bootstrap for instance?

Comment: Please show your Html code.

Comment: maybe you can table with 3 columns bootstrap and ng-repeat using index

Comment: there are indeed multiple ways to accomplish this, and it has been discussed at length in multiple questions here already.  Here is one prominent example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27211799/angular-ng-repeat-add-bootstrap-row-every-3-or-4-cols

Answer (score 3):

This is a functionality of css. No need to any angular code. Just put your ng-repeat in `<li>` inside of `<ul>` and put a style for `<ul>` tag `columns: 3`. You will achieve your requirement.

#### Example

```
<ul style="columns:3">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved in multiple ways.

- You can use 3 columns structure to implement this. so after three
  values it will automatically come down to next line.
- You can achieve this in tour code as well. use an ng-if on **"br"** tag
  when $index%3 == 2.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to structure like that. One way is to format array into a 2D array for proper looping. Check out the **[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vrpruthvi/Lgyhmshr/4/)**.

Create filter to format your array data:

```
// Loop every n items filter
App.filter("loopEvery", [function() {
  return function(mainArray, loopEvery) {
    var subArray = [], formattedArray = [];
    angular.forEach(mainArray, function(item, index) {
      subArray.push(item);
      if ((subArray.length == loopEvery) || (index == mainArray.length - 1)) {
        formattedArray.push(subArray);
        subArray = [];
      }
    });
    return formattedArray;
  }
}]);
```

Comment: Nice. Actually i wanted this. Thanks.