# How to print array in a row using ng-repeat with limit of 6 items in Angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to print array items like

```
 a b c d e f
 g h i j k l
 m n o p q r
```

My array is ["a","b","c","d","e"...] like up to r

I tried like ths

```
<div ng-repeat="array in arraylist | limitTo:6">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" >
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>{{array}} </label>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

But it printing up to f, then how to print all elements in  above format?

Comment: so you want to print 6 char per row right?

Comment: You don't need to use limit here, but actually you need to keep track through index to take new div , Here it's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27211799/angular-ng-repeat-add-bootstrap-row-every-3-or-4-cols

Comment: that linked question is *very similar*, with the exception of the number being repeated over.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the limitTo filter it just limits to number of item in an array.Now coming to your problem it can be easily solved by putting a empty div with bootstrap class col-xs-12,col-sm-12,col-lg-12 applied and this div would be shown only when $index%6 is 0.Code sample is as follows.

```
 <div ng-repeat="array in arraylist">
       <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" ng-if="($index)%6==0"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>
                    {{array}}
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[**limitTo**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)

> Creates a new array or string containing **only a specified number of**
>   **elements**.

But you need to iterate over the entire `array`. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/divyanshu013/3Lpqexnd/2/) fiddle:

```
<div ng-repeat="alphabet in alphabets" ng-if="$index % 6 == 0" class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">{{alphabets[$index]}}</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">{{alphabets[$index + 1]}}</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">{{alphabets[$index + 2]}}</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">{{alphabets[$index + 3]}}</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">{{alphabets[$index + 4]}}</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">{{alphabets[$index + 5]}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
 var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("listController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {


    $scope.results = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r"];


  }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
 <div ng-repeat="product in results" ng-if="$index % 6 == 0" class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-2">{{results[$index]}}</div>
     <div class="col-xs-2">{{results[$index + 1]}}</div>
     <div class="col-xs-2">{{results[$index + 2]}}</div>
     <div class="col-xs-2">{{results[$index + 3]}}</div>
     <div class="col-xs-2">{{results[$index + 4]}}</div>
     <div class="col-xs-2">{{results[$index + 5]}}</div>  
 </div>
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("listController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {


    $scope.results = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r"];

   
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.5/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

  <script data-require="jquery@1.11.3" data-semver="1.11.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller="listController" class="row">

   <div ng-repeat="result in results" ng-if="$index % 6 == 0" class="row">
<div class="col-xs-2">{{results[$index]}}</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">{{results[$index + 1]}}</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">{{results[$index + 2]}}</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">{{results[$index + 3]}}</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">{{results[$index + 4]}}</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">{{results[$index + 5]}}</div>
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: where is f,l,r?

Answer (score -1):

What i can understand from your example is that you want to give a line break after sixth element in your array. if that the case, this might able to you.

```
<div ng-repeat="array in arraylist ">
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" >
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>{{array}} <br ng-if="$index%6 == 0 " /> </label>
          </div> 
        </div>
</div>
```