# AngularJS Ionic create dynamic table with 5 columns

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create a dynamic table using ionic and AngularJS with exactly 5 columns for each rows. How do I traverse JSON DOM so I don't repeat the same record 5 times each row. Here's the structure of my tags. Many thanks.

```
<div class=“row” hg-repeat=“item in items”ng-controller=“myController”>
<div class=“col col-15”>
    <div class=“row”>
        <div class=“col col-25”>{{item.productName}}</div>
        <div class=“col col-75”>{{item.price}}</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class=“col col-15”>
    <div class=“row”>
        <div class=“col col-25”>{{item.productName}}</div>
        <div class=“col col-75”>{{item.price}</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class=“col col-15”>
    <div class=“row”>
        <div class=“col col-25”>{{item.productName}}</div>
        <div class=“col col-75”>{{item.price}</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class=“col col-15”>
    <div class=“row”>
        <div class=“col col-25”>{{item.productName}}</div>
        <div class=“col col-75”>{{item.price}</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class=“col col-15”>
    <div class=“row”>
        <div class=“col col-25”>{{item.productName}}</div>
        <div class=“col col-75”>{{item.price}</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How many rows you want?

Comment: Depend on the data. This part is dynamic.

Comment: There may only be 2 or 3 columns in the last row. Thanks for asking

Comment: this is very similar, and there are a few different methods listed.  You should be able to adapt one of the methods listed for your purpose: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27211799/angular-ng-repeat-add-bootstrap-row-every-3-or-4-cols

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out.

Comment: no they don't work. They don't display the first few rows. and traversing JSON DOM by way of $index doesn't work.  I tried many different variations.

Comment: I did this simple codes in PHP.  Is there anyway we can do this using JavaScript    $sample = 17;
     
            for ($n = 1; $n <= $sample; $n++) {

                    $x=0;
                    
                   if ($n==1 OR $x==$n+1) {echo"<tr>";}
                        echo "<td><div id='blue'>$n</div></td>";
                       
                        
                   if ($n%5==0 OR $n==$sample) {echo"</tr>"; $x=$n+1;}
            }