# Angular 4 *ngFor adding a row div every third column

Tags: angular, ngfor, bulma

I am using Angular 4 with the [bulma css framework](http://bulma.io/) and I am wondering how I can add a new row (or columns class) every third column.

The index variable which prints out 0,1,2 0,1,2 etc. was when I looking at a [snippet](https://gist.github.com/JefCurtis/666a8885b82aca7ab62d) when using bootstrap.

Noticed some comments on maybe I can use the [template syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax) but didn't get that to work either.

```
<div class="columns">
    <div class="column is-one-third" *ngFor="let item of items | async; let index = index">
      <app-item-details [item]='item '></app-item-details>
      {{ index % 3 }}
    <div class="is-clearfix" *ngIf="index % 3 == 0"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ng-if = `*ngIf`

Comment: Please provide the expected output in your question, because I don't understand what you mean here.

Comment: Yea noticed I type that *ngIf wrong, but that is for the bootstrap snippet so didn't expect that to work when using the bulma framework. (it didn't help either) What I need is to wrap my result around a new columns class every third item in loop.

Comment: Same as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27211799/angular-ng-repeat-add-bootstrap-row-every-3-or-4-cols but with using bulma and angular 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change the condition in *ngIf as below.

```
*ngIf="(index + 1) % 4 == 0"
```

Plunker example : https://plnkr.co/edit/C0DrgY3Rty33ZRhyML7E?p=preview

Comment: I think the OP wants to add a div after every 3, in your plunker after first iteration, row gets added after every 4. So, I made some tweaks to your [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CUXb1ubGBNUW13KUAm2b?p=preview) :)

Comment: howcome plunker just says `loading...` ?? cant see any of you guys example rendered on the html.  Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1):

Below Solution work for me:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-4" *ngFor="let item of productimages; let index = index">
            <img [src]="item.image">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]