# How to repeat image column in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

How to set items per line in a column?

Here is HTML code:

```
<td ng-repeat="dr in img">
     <input id="imBed" ng-model="q" type="image" ng-src="{{dr.IMG}}" style="width: 50px;height: 50px" ng-click="Save(dr)" />
      <span ng-model="dr.BEDNO" style="width:60px">{{dr.BEDNO}} </span>
</td>
```

Comment: show the controller code

Comment: can you clarify your question so you want is to set how many imgs per row ???

Comment: 6 items per line

Comment: you have to capture image and then save? or just only show img in columns

Comment: just only show img in columns

Comment: A quick question: Why you're using expressions (``{{}}``) since you're using `ng-src`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i did mine if you use bootstrap you can use `col-md-2` so in one row/line you can have 6 images.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2" ng-repeat="dr in img">
    <img class="card-img-top" ng-src="{{ dr.IMG }}">
    <span ng-model="dr.BEDNO" style="width:60px">{{dr.BEDNO}} </span>
</div></div>
```

Note `ng-repeat` must be inside `<div class="row"></div`

if you want a more programmatically approach refer to this [post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27211799/angular-ng-repeat-add-bootstrap-row-every-3-or-4-cols)

Comment: I don't use bootstrap, Please give solution without bootstrap.