# Angular with bootstrap ngFor repeat row every 3 items

Tags: angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to line up 3 mat-card items next to each other but for some reasons it just doesn't want to go in the right position. I followed the answers given in this thread ( [Angular ng-repeat add bootstrap row every 3 or 4 cols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27211799/angular-ng-repeat-add-bootstrap-row-every-3-or-4-cols) ).

The code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div *ngFor='let session of sessions' ng-if="$index % 3 == 0" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <mat-card class="example-card">

      <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title class="title">{{session.session_name}}</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle>{{session.speakers[0].name}}</mat-card-subtitle>
      </mat-card-header>


      <mat-chip color="accent" class="pull-right" selected>{{session.level}}</mat-chip>

      <img mat-card-image height="150px" [src]="session.sessionImgUrl" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">

      <mat-card-content>

        <mat-accordion class="accordion">
          <mat-expansion-panel hideToggle>
            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
              <mat-panel-title>
                Lees meer.
              </mat-panel-title>
              <mat-panel-description>

              </mat-panel-description>
            </mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <p>{{session.speakers[0].name}}</p>
            <mat-chip-list aria-label="categories">
              <div *ngFor='let category of session.categories'>
                <mat-chip color="secondary">{{category}}</mat-chip>
              </div>
            </mat-chip-list>
          </mat-expansion-panel>
        </mat-accordion>
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Screen of the result (where they should be next to each other):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ngFor is on the division with the `row` class, you want to move that to the div below where you define the `col` class. You also don't need the modulo operator because bootstrap will wrap onto a new line for you automatically.

```
<div class="row">
    <div *ngFor='let session of sessions' class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
```